# Undefined Reference to Constructor when I have it explicitly "type out"

Tags: c++, singleton, undefined-reference

Here is the code, why am I getting an undefined reference while linking?

```
g++ -Wall -o main main.o TimerManager.o
TimerManager.o: In function `TimerManager::Instance()':
TimerManager.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `TimerManager::TimerManager()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

--

```
#include "TimerManager.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  TimerManager *l_tm = TimerManager::Instance();
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
#ifndef TIMERMANAGER_H_
#define TIMERMANAGER_H_

#include <stdlib.h>

class TimerManager {
public:
  static TimerManager *Instance();
  ~TimerManager();
protected:
  TimerManager();
private:
  static TimerManager *s_instance;
};

#endif
```

---

```
#include "TimerManager.h"

TimerManager *TimerManager::s_instance = NULL;

TimerManager::TimerManager()
{
}

TimerManager::~TimerManager()
{
  delete s_instance;
}

TimerManager *TimerManager::Instance() {
  if (s_instance == NULL) {
    s_instance = new TimerManager();
  }
  return s_instance;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your object file is out of date.

This compiles and links for me:

```
% g++ -Wall -o main main.cpp TimerManager.cpp
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:5:17: warning: unused variable 'l_tm' [-Wunused-variable]
```